# ArcGIS Pro 2.4 .NET SDK: calling templatized class instance methods from Python?

Tags: arcgis-pro-sdk

I'm trying to do some learning with the ArcGIS Pro 2.4 .NET SDK in the Pro application's Python window:

```
import clr
import ArcGIS.Desktop.Core as ADC

for i in ADC.Project.Current.Items:
    print(i)
```

This works. Does anyone know the Python syntax for calling methods like `Project.GetItems<T>()`, if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

`ADC.Project.Current.GetItems[ArcGIS.Dekstop.Layouts.LayoutProjectItem]()` gets a list of LayoutProjectItems.